# Possibly missing records in AWS lambda function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Node.js Lambda function that I am trying to work with to process an input data set from a SQS queue. I had this function working about 3 weeks ago and have made zero code changes and no conifg changes on AWS. However I am getting an error message in CloudWatch Logs where it says it can't read the `0` place as my code is trying to do.

Lambda function cut down

```
module.exports.perf = function (event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let input = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
  console.log(input)

  return true
};
```

Error message

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.module.exports.perf [as handler] (/var/task/handler.js:15:39)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

Due to only posting part of the file where the error message refers to line 15 it coresponds with line 4 of the provided code.

I've removed most of the lambda function because it fails at the mentioned line and doesn't run the rest of the code anyways so including it is just fuzzing the issue.

I can check SQS to make sure the body exists and it does on the messages that the lambda is processing. I do this via unsubscribing it from the SQS queue using the console then I wait till messages are in the queue and check to make sure the body is as expected. Though it seems it's failing on the `Records[0]` part not the body.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong here?

EDIT**

Seem to have resolved the issue overnight, I'm not sure what happened however when I ran a test again by adding a message to SQS as I did when posting this I saw working results in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: Are you sure that SQS is the only thing that invokes your function?

Comment: The simplest approach is `console.log(event)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))`... the explanation should become readily apparent.